# Quel est le sens de l'expression « un entre-deux » en ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, littérature

Dans le roman *S'adapter* de Clara Dupond-Monod on lit (l'emphase est mienne) :

> Parfois son père ébouriffait ses cheveux avec une tendresse alarmée, une brusquerie qui révélait une crainte, celle de le voir partir, comme s’il fallait le retenir, lui, le dernier, parce que avant lui il y avait eu la souffrance et après lui il n’y aurait rien. Il se tenait dans **un entre-deux**. Il était à la fois un nouveau départ et une continuité, une fracture et une promesse.

J'ai lu le contenu de l'[entrée "entre-deux" dans les TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre-deux), mais aucune mention a l'expression « un entre-deux » n'est présente. Cependant, une recherche sur Internet de cette locution donne plusieurs résultats. Est-ce que quelqu'un pourrait expliquer son sens dans le texte cité?

Comment: Dans le texte cité il s'agit du sens B2 du TLFi. Le fait que dans le TLFi n'ait pas retenu d'exemple avec l'article indéfini  n'empêche pas que cet emploi soit possible. Le choix de l'article défini ou indéfini relève de l'auteur. Parmi les exemples du [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/entredeux) deux emploient l'article indéfini, un dans le wiktionnaire.

Comment: Cela peut sembler idiot, mais à cause de la présence du mot "deux", j'avais pensé au chiffre "un" et non à l'article indéfini "un".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Le fait que le TLFi n'ait pas retenu d'exemple où le nom *entre-deux* soit précédé d'un article indéfini n'empêche pas que cet emploi soit possible. Le choix de l'article défini ou indéfini relève de l'auteur. Dans la phrase de Clara Dupond-Monod le mot est employé avec le sens B2 du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/entre-deux) :

> État intermédiaire entre deux extrêmes.

Parmi les exemples du [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/entredeux) on trouve un exemple où *entredeux** est employé avec l'article indéfini :

> Et l'on comprend que la démarche (méta)méthodologique nous contraint à opter pour la deuxième possibilité en ce qu'elle expose un entredeux. (*Rue Descartes, 2001, Eberhard Gruber (Cairn.info)*)

De même dans [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/entredeux_ou_entre-deux) :

> Se trouver dans un entredeux.

Dans les deux cas il s'agit de se trouver dans un état intermédiaire mais les extrêmes ne sont pas définis, du moins à cette étape de la rédaction.

Dans l'exemple suivant trouvé dans le TLFi :

> Nous autres avons peur de la foudre et végétons comme nous pouvons, dans l'entre-deux de la vérité et du mensonge, le clair-obscur de la justice et de l'injustice mêlées (Guéhenno, Jean-Jacques,1948).

l'auteur emploie l'article défini parce que le mot est défini par le groupe de mots : « de la vérité et du mensonge ».

Dans sa phrase Clara Dupond-Monod ne définit pas l'entre-deux dans lequel elle situe son personnage, c'est à mon avis un choix délibéré à ce stade, peut-être pour laisser le lecteur en suspens, car dans la phrase suivante elle  laisse le lecteur entrevoir les extrêmes possibles.

---

<sup>*Les deux orthographes sont possibles : *entre-deux* ou *entredeux*</sup>